# Explode sem foreach

Tags: php

Colegas.

Estou trazendo do banco as notas dos alunos que estão da seguinte forma:

> C,D,A,C,A,E,A,B,C,C,B,D,A,C,D,D,B,B,B,A

Porém preciso comparar com as notas do gabarito que vem de um XML e graças a ajuda dos colegas, cheguei ao seguinte código:

```
   $contar = 0;
    $notasAlunos = explode(',',$aluno->avaliacao_respostas);
    foreach($xml->avaliacao->disciplina as $disciplina) {
           echo $disciplina->attributes()->nome.":<br>";
           foreach ($disciplina as $questao) {
                    foreach($notasAlunos as $notaAluno){ // Aqui trago as notas dos alunos
                            if($questao->resposta == $notaAluno){ // aqui verifico se as questões do gabarito é igual a nota do aluno
                               $conta = $contar++;                       
                           }                
                    }   
           }
    }
echo $conta;
```

O único problema é que as quando uso dessa forma, em vez de me trazer 17 pontos, está me trazendo 91.

Comment: `$conta = $contar++;` isso é redundância.

Comment: Olá Diego... certo.... qual a melhor forma?

Comment: Veja [aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.increment.php) E o problema não seria porque está somando as notas de todas as disciplinas como se fossem uma só?

Comment: @DiegoF nao é redundância, é um bug sério, pois fica imprevisível o resultado (depende de implementação e pode mudar).

Comment: Desculpe diego... sua resposta ficou muito vaga e não me ajudou muito... não é isso que estou fazendo?

Comment: Jose você não deixou claro o pretende na pergunta. Pelo que entendi, você quer somar as notas das questoes, por disciplinas e exibir de cada uma, mas seu código está somando todas as respostas de todas as disciplinas.

Comment: Desculpe diego, aqui só apareceu o "Veja aqui" e não apareceu o restante de sua resposta, por isso pareceu vaga... Desculpe por isso..

Comment: @Bacco Não entendi, o que é bug? Até onde sei, ao fazer um incremento `$contar++`, a propria linguagem já faz `$contar = $contar + 1`, logo, seria reundancia,

Comment: O que preciso é fazer a comparação das notas dos alunos com a do gabarito que está vindo de um arquivo XML. Os resultados do XML estou conseguindo trazer, mas quando faço a comparação, em vez de calcular 17, aparece 91

Comment: Cada acerto seria 1 ponto...

Comment: José, seu objetivo é somar os acertos das questoes por disciplina, ou somar todos os acertos, independente da disciplina que for? talvez mostrando um trecho de como o xml está na pergunta, dê uma noção pra gente de como você deveria tratar esses dados,

Comment: Isso.. somar os acertos das questões por disciplina. Ex.: Matemática: 4 acertos, Física: 5 acertos...

Comment: @DiegoF o ++ incrementa a variável DEPOIS de fazer a atribuição (igual). O problema neste caso é que dependendo de como a linguagem processa isso, o valor pode ou não ser incrementado. Contar com comportamento implícito por si só já é péssimo. Nesses casos, com ambiguidade, pior ainda. E mesmo que você teste e funcione, numa mudança de versão de linguagem pode mudar o comportamento.

Comment: José, como te falei, do jeito que está, você está incrementando TODOS os acertos, independente de disciplina. você deve guardar a soma de acertos após terminar o loop em uma disciplina e zera o $contar para outra disciplina, repetindo esse ciclo.

Comment: Entendi.... teria como me mostrar um exemplo? pois não estou encontrando um raciocínio para essa solução.

Comment: @Bacco Esquece, entendi, realmente não é redundância, é erro semântico mesmo.

Comment: @DiegoF mas nao tá errado o que vc disse, só alertei pra um perigo maior. Em principio, o "efeito" é apenas redundante mesmo. O problema é que não tem como garantir que o comportamento seja o esperado sempre. (a não ser que em algum lugar da documentação do PHP explicitasse o que acontece nestes casos, aí faria parte do design da linguagem, aí seria apenas "retrabalho" desnecessário mesmo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente desta forma:

```
$contar = 0;
$notasAlunos = explode(',',$aluno->avaliacao_respostas);
foreach($xml->avaliacao->disciplina as $disciplina) {
    echo $disciplina->attributes()->nome.":<br>";
    foreach ($disciplina as $key => $questao) {
        if($questao->resposta == $notaAluno[$key]){
            $contar++;                       
        }                  
    }
    echo $contar;
    $contar = 0;
}
```

Assim, você exibe a nota da disciplina assim que o laço responsável por contar os acertos terminar, e em seguida, zera a variavel para que ela não some valores de acertos de outras disciplinas.

Comment: Olá Diego. Fiz dessa forma, porém continua me retornando 91. Estranho mesmo. Quando coloquei o print dentro do laço, ele me retorna: 4
8
13
18
23
24
29
34
39
43
48
52
57
62
67
71
76
81
86
91
O XML retorna as respostas corretas na mesma ordem da resposta dos alunos

Comment: @Jose.Marcos acontece que sem ver como seu xml está, fica dificil melhorar o código. Adicione um trecho do xml com as respostas certas.

Comment: Estou achando que a linha foreach($notasAlunos as $notaAluno){ está dando esse problema. Existe algum meio de pegar as notas do aluno sem o foreach?

Comment: @Jose.Marcos é garantido que o numero de respostas em $notasAlunos é sempre o total de questoes de todas as disciplinas do xml?

Comment: Oi Diego... não... pois alguns alunos deixam algumas respostas em branco....

Comment: @Jose.Marcos então não é possivel fazer isso, inclusive você terá problemas, pois ao não registrar uma resposta, na hora de comparar as que forem respondidas, a comparacao será errada(Ex. não respondeu a questao 2 e respondeu a 3, seu código vai comparar a resposta certa da questao 2 com a resposta da 3). Você deve tratar de alguma forma as questoes sem respostas, para que isso não ocorra.

Comment: Oi Diego. Desculpe. Confirmei com o coordenador da escola pelo what e ele informou que as respostas sao obrigatórias.... ou seja... a quantidade das respostas dos alunos correspondem com a  quantidade do gabarito

Comment: @Jose.Marcos veja se dessa forma exibe corretamente

Comment: Funcionou Diego. Obrigado pela ajuda de mais uma vez desculpe pelo meu mal entendido.